# Getting an 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', invalid number of rows in section 0 error while inserting and deleting?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

while trying to insert a row, the tableview crashes saying "'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (0), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'"
it also crashes when i try to delete a row row saying "'attempt to insert row 0 into section 0, but there are only 0 rows in section 0 after the update'"

This is an SDK cloned from Github named antidote.tried only using tableview.reloaddata() instead of begin and end updates and vice versa.

the link for the same is : https://github.com/Antidote-for-Tox/Antidote

## FriendListController

```
super.viewDidLoad()

    let friends = submanagerObjects.friends()
    let requests = submanagerObjects.friendRequests()
    dataSource = FriendListDataSource(theme: theme, friends: 
friends, requests: requests)
    dataSource.delegate = self

    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()

    updateViewsVisibility()
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    updateViewsVisibility()
}

extension FriendListController: FriendListDataSourceDelegate {

    func friendListDataSourceBeginUpdates() {
        tableView.beginUpdates()
    }

    func friendListDataSourceEndUpdates() {
        tableView.endUpdates()
        updateViewsVisibility()
    }

    func friendListDataSourceInsertRowsAtIndexPaths(_ indexPaths: [IndexPath]) {
        tableView.insertRows(at: indexPaths, with: .automatic)
    }

    func friendListDataSourceDeleteRowsAtIndexPaths(_ indexPaths: [IndexPath]) {
        tableView.deleteRows(at: indexPaths, with: .automatic)
    }

    func friendListDataSourceReloadRowsAtIndexPaths(_ indexPaths: [IndexPath]) {
        tableView.reloadRows(at: indexPaths, with: .automatic)
    }

    func friendListDataSourceInsertSections(_ sections: IndexSet) {
        tableView.insertSections(sections, with: .automatic)
    }

    func friendListDataSourceDeleteSections(_ sections: IndexSet) {
        tableView.deleteSections(sections, with: .automatic)
    }

    func friendListDataSourceReloadSections(_ sections: IndexSet) {
        tableView.reloadSections(sections, with: .automatic)
    }

    func friendListDataSourceReloadTable() {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

extension FriendListController: UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: FriendListCell.staticReuseIdentifier) as! FriendListCell
        let model = dataSource.modelAtIndexPath(indexPath)

        cell.setupWithTheme(theme, model: model)

        return cell
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return dataSource.numberOfSections()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataSource.numberOfRowsInSection(section)
    }

    func sectionIndexTitles(for tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
        return dataSource.sectionIndexTitles()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return dataSource.titleForHeaderInSection(section)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: 
UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            let title: String

            switch dataSource.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
            case .request:
                title = String(localized:"delete_contact_request_title")
            case .friend:
                title = String(localized:"delete_contact_title")
            }

            let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)

            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: String(localized: "alert_cancel"), style: .default, handler: nil))
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: String(localized: "alert_delete"), style: .destructive) { [unowned self] _ -> Void in

                switch self.dataSource.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
                case .request(let request):
                    self.submanagerFriends.remove(request)
                case .friend(let friend):
                    do {
                        let chat = 
 self.submanagerChats.getOrCreateChat(with: friend)

                        try self.submanagerFriends.remove(friend)
                        self.submanagerChats.removeAllMessages(in: chat, removeChat: true)
                    } catch let error as NSError {
                             handleErrorWithType(.removeFriend, error: error)
                        }
                 }
            })

            present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

## FriendListDataSource

```
private extension FriendListDataSource {

    func addNotificationBlocks() {
        requestsToken = requests?.addNotificationBlock { [unowned self] change in
        switch change {
        case .initial:
            break
        case .update(let requests, let deletions, let insertions, let modifications):
            guard let requests = requests else { return }
            if deletions.count > 0 {
                self.delegate?.friendListDataSourceReloadTable()
                return
            }
            self.delegate?.friendListDataSourceBeginUpdates()

            let countAfter = requests.count
            let countBefore = countAfter - insertions.count + deletions.count

            if countBefore == 0 && countAfter > 0 {
                self.delegate?.friendListDataSourceInsertSections(IndexSet(integer: 0))
            } else { 
                    self.delegate?.friendListDataSourceDeleteRowsAtIndexPaths(deletions.map { IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0)} )
                    self.delegate?.friendListDataSourceInsertRowsAtIndexPaths(insertions.map { IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0)} )
                    self.delegate?.friendListDataSourceReloadRowsAtIndexPaths(modifications.map { IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0)} )  
                }
                 self.delegate?.friendListDataSourceEndUpdates()
        case .error(let error):
            fatalError("\(error)")
        }
    }
```

it is supposed to work without crashes thou it crashes on insertion and deletion the former produces "'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (0), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'"
the later produces : "'attempt to insert row 0 into section 0, but there are only 0 rows in section 0 after the update.'"

any help is appreciated.

Comment: before editing tableview, you should edit array your tableview based on

Answer (score 1):

According to [UITableView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview) class you must use one of the following:

- `performBatchUpdates(_:completion:)` ([link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/2887515-performbatchupdates))
- `func beginUpdates()` ([link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614908-beginupdates)) and then `func endUpdates()` ([link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614890-endupdates))

**You MUST perform all updates inside the batch update block** (or between the begin and the end update functions) (including the data source update - not only the insert/delete/move/reload)

By that you will avoid the crash.

for example:

```
var dataSource: [Int] = [1, 2, 3]

tableView.beginUpdates()
dataSource.append(4)
tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 3, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
tableView.endUpdates()
```

Comment: every operation is between begin updates and end updates

Comment: every refresh should have: updating the data source + insert/move/delete/reload. It's better to combine it to singe begin/end or single batch completion block... more efficient and you gain the iOS animations - I will update the answer to expain

Comment: check the simple code example I've added. I think it will be clearer...

Comment: In your example `beginUpdates/endUpdates` is completely useless. It has no effect at all for a single `insert/delete/move` operation.

Comment: The example was to show the order of things.. the begin/end-Updates is for multi insertion/deletion/moving

Comment: i got the point but my tableview oprations happens through delegate calls thats why the begin and end updates are like that. can you suggest what changes should i make in my code to work

Comment: Well if the update is according to user action, it's simple - just surround it with begin and update. If it's according to network request, add delegate functions for begin and end the updates - and then you can call all the insert/delete/move/reload between those delegates.